# How can I get the value of 'data-wpid'

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div class="buyButtonNoPrice" data-wpid="3218954"></div>
```

This is the code I have tried but it does not work

```
var CLASS = document.querySelector("[class='buyButtonNoPrice']")
console.log(CLASS)
```

when I log class i am returned with this html
`<div class="buyButtonNoPrice" data-wpid="3218954"></div>`

i have tried to get the attribute by trying this too:

````
console.log(CLASS)```
that sort of thing works in python but not js
````

Comment: Hello, you'll easily find the answer with a search engine (like Duckduckgo or Google).

Comment: @Amessihel I've tried to look for an answer but nothing seems to work

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] and what you tried from your researches?

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` is for selecting DOM elements. You've already found the element, it's in the `CLASS` variable.

The method for getting the value of an attribute is `getAttribute()`, e.g. `CLASS.getAttribute("data-wpid")`. But you can use the `dataset` property to access `data-XXX` attributes directly.

```js
var CLASS = document.querySelector("[class='buyButtonNoPrice']")
var PID = CLASS.dataset.wpid;
console.log(PID)
```

```html
<div class="buyButtonNoPrice" data-wpid="3218954"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, that's amazing!!! i can do this in python just not JS

Answer (score 0):

To select any node by an attribute, you must use brackets around the attribute name:

```
// example: <div data-wpid="3218954" bing="baz">...</div>
const node1 = document.querySelector('[data-wpid]')
const node2 = document.querySelector('[bing]')
assert(node1 === node2) //-> true
```

Once you have selected a node, you get the value of all `data-*` attributes from the `dataset` property:

```
// example: <div data-wpid="3218954" data-foo="bar">...</div>
const node = document.querySelector('[data-wpid]')
const wpid = node.dataset.wpid  //-> 3218954
const foo = node.dataset.foo    //-> "bar"
```

Using `querySelector` is nice because you can pass any valid CSS selector. There are other common selectors which pre-date `querySelector:

```
// example: <div id="foo" class="bar bing">...</div>
const byId = document.getElementById('foo')
const byClass1 = document.getElementsByClassName('bar') // returns array or null
const byClass2 = document.getElementsByClassName('bing') // returns array or null
const byTag = document.getElementsByTagName('div') // return array or null
assert(byId === byClass1[0]) //-> true
assert(byId === byClass2[0]) //-> true
assert(byId === byTag[0])    //-> true
```